# smtp mail sending

Tags: c++, smtp

i want to integrate smtp mail sending option in my vc++ application
please any one provide the class or lib whch can be integrated

Answer (score 0):

How about [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) ?

Comment: This is a .NET class.The question is about C++

Answer (score 0):

[Ultimate TCP/IP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateTCPIP.aspx) is free, Visual Studio friendly and supports SMTP.  Highly recommended.

Comment: hi all,
i have written the smtp client module ,and its working, 
but after connecting to server( like gmail),i am getting response that STARTTLS COMMAND should be issued,
please help me on this